# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'

Tags: python

```
def comprobar_numero(variable_global):
    while any(chr.isalpha() for chr in variable_global):
        variable_global = input("el valor debe ser un numero entero: ")

if calcular == "densidad":
    print("\n-----Calculando densidad-----")
    volumen = input("ingrese el volumen del cuerpo: ")
    variable_global = volumen
    comprobar_numero(variable_global)
    volumen = variable_global

    masa = input("ingrese la masa: ")
    variable_global = masa
    comprobar_numero(variable_global)
    masa = variable_global
    print(variable_global)
    densidad = float(masa)/float(volumen)
    print("La densidad es", densidad, "\n")
```

el error #----------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/programacion/notas.py", line 35, in 
densidad = float(masa)/float(volumen)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
PS C:\Users\Mati\Desktop\www>

Answer (score 2):

1- La ejecución del código empieza en `if calcular == "densidad":` Si esto es porque hay un menú, omitir este punto. De lo contrario, la variable `calcular` no estará definida.

2- `comprobar_numero(variable_global)` Este llamado a función no hace nada importante en el código. Solo imprimir por pantalla si el valor es válido o no. Si el valor no es válido, de igual forma entrará en la formula provocando el error porque no hay un `return` con el valor correcto.

3- Ya que esa función `comprobar_numero()` también pide datos de entrada por teclado en caso de tener caracteres incorrectos, entonces ¿por qué no dejarle toda la entrada a esa función?

Siguiendo esos puntos, el programa quedaría así:

```
def comprobar_numero(mensaje):
    while True:
        var = input(mensaje)
        if any(chr.isalpha() for chr in var):
            print("[Error] el valor debe ser un numero entero\n")
        else:
            return var


print("\n-----Calculando densidad-----")
volumen = comprobar_numero("ingrese el volumen del cuerpo: ")
masa = comprobar_numero("ingrese la masa: ")
densidad = float(masa)/float(volumen)
print("La densidad es", densidad, "\n")
```

Comment: Creo q `isalpha` no es suficiente. A lo mejor hay q utilizar regex `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`. También a mi me parece buena idea hacer un `try except` con la conversión a float dentro del `while`. Así solo sales si el resultado es un float.

Answer (score 1):

el problema se da porque `comprobar_numero(variable_global)` recibe la variable `variable_global` como un argumento por ende el alcance de la misma queda restringido a la función puedes hacer un `return` para que regrese el valor o simplemente remover el argumento

## ejemplos:

ejemplo 1:

```
def comprobar_numero():
    global variable_global
    while any(chr.isalpha() for chr in variable_global):
        variable_global = input("el valor debe ser un numero entero: ")


print("\n-----Calculando densidad-----")
volumen = input("ingrese el volumen del cuerpo: ")
variable_global = volumen
comprobar_numero()
volumen = variable_global

masa = input("ingrese la masa: ")
variable_global = masa
comprobar_numero()
masa = variable_global
print(variable_global)
densidad = float(masa)/float(volumen)
print("La densidad es", densidad, "\n")
```

opcion 2:

```
def comprobar_numero(variable_global):
    while any(chr.isalpha() for chr in variable_global):
        variable_global = input("el valor debe ser un numero entero: ")
    return variable_global

print("\n-----Calculando densidad-----")
volumen = input("ingrese el volumen del cuerpo: ")
volumen = comprobar_numero(volumen)

masa = input("ingrese la masa: ")
masa = comprobar_numero(masa)

densidad = float(masa)/float(volumen)
print("La densidad es", densidad, "\n")
```